# In angularjs how to pass ngModel object to another view?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application

I have 2 partial pages in angularjs single page application. In page 1 I take input from user as ngModel and on next button click based on that i show someimage in next partial page. If User likes it there is option to save the current model data but on this page I don't have ngModel. How can i access model object on 2nd partial page submission?

Comment: It's generally easier to help if you provide some code, as well as anything you have already tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a service like

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).service("MyService",function(){return {myValue:{}})
```

or you could use angular value

```
angular.module("myApp",[]).
  value("myValue", {}).
  controller("MyCtrl1", function($scope, myValue){
    $scope.someValue = myValue;
  }).
  controller("MyCtrl2", function($scope, myValue){
    $scope.someValue = myValue;
  })
```

or you could use $routeParams to pass the value if it's an id or the like.

Answer (score 4):

To share some data between page transitions you can simply use `$cacheFactory` [service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24cacheFactory).

Another more straightforward way is to save data to `$rootScope`.
All controller scopes is inherited from the root scope, so you can save some data to $rootScope variable on first page and then access it via $scope on next page.